# Python using ZIP64 extensions when compressing large files

Tags: python, zip, zlib, python-zipfile

I have a script that compresses the output files. The problem is that one of the files is over 4Gigs. How would I convert my script to use ZIP64 extensions instead of the standard zip?

Here is how I am currently zipping:

```
try:
    import zlib
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
except:
    compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED

modes = { zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED: 'deflated',
          zipfile.ZIP_STORED:   'stored',
          } 

compressed_name = 'edw_files_' + datetime.strftime(date(), '%Y%m%d') + '.zip' 
print 'creating archive'
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('edw_files_' + datetime.strftime(date(), '%Y%m%d') + '.zip', mode='w')
try:
    zf.write(name1, compress_type=compression)
    zf.write(name2, compress_type=compression)
    zf.write(name3, compress_type=compression)
finally:
    print 'closing'
    zf.close()
```

Answer (score 20):

Check out [zipfile-objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects).

You can do this:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('edw_files_' + datetime.strftime(date(), '%Y%m%d') + '.zip', mode='w', allowZip64 = True)
```

Comment: But, allowZip64 default value is True

Comment: Sorry!
Default isTrue just Python 3. Python 2 default is False

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('edw_files_' + datetime.strftime(date(), '%Y%m%d') + '.zip', mode='w', allowZip64=True)
```